# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.visual studio error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in **getitem**
    o = self.datakey
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Karan Shah.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in 
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Karan Shah.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Karan Shah.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='**main**')
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Karan Shah\Desktop\Jarvis.py", line 9, in 
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in **init**
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Karan Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in **init**

Comment: Did you just post the entire traceback and expect an output? Not even going to downvote. You need spiritual guidance, my child.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear regarding the issue specified. Looks like there is a conflict  in the dll files. Could you check if you are using 32 bit python if you have downloaded the visual studio 32 bit version.

It would be of better practice to use 64 bit python as well a visual studio 64 bit version.

Comment: I have downloaded both python 64 and 32 bit version and can u give me the link for vs-code 32 bit and vs-code 64 bit version.

Comment: 32 bit [link]https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/3db7e09f3b61f915d03bbfa58e258d6eee843f35/VSCode-win32-ia32-1.38.0.zip                                                                                      64 bit [link]https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/3db7e09f3b61f915d03bbfa58e258d6eee843f35/VSCode-win32-x64-1.38.0.zip